# how to use different tables in UI which accesses full screen size accordingly?

Tags: android, design-patterns

i want to use 3-4 tables in a single screen but can't fit them in whole screen beside using "fill_parent". it come to only with size of the text in that table only. Can anyone guide me?
i used following code.

```
<TableLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0"
                android:id="@+id/Table1"
                >

            <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                        android:background="#00bfff" 
                        android:text="@string/hello" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            </TextView>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0"
                android:layout_below="@id/Table1"
                android:id="@+id/Table2"
                >

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                        android:background="#f4a460"
                        android:text="Text2" >
            </TextView>
</TableLayout>      

<TableLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0"
                android:id="@+id/Table3"
                android:layout_below="@id/Table1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Table2"
                >

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                        android:background="#b03060"
                        android:text="Text3" >
            </TextView>
</TableLayout>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

In table2 and table3 change the

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```